# haskell & gtk : "widgetGetDrawWindow: no DrawWindow available"

Tags: haskell, plot, gtk

I have a little program expected to draw the mandelbrot set but I get this error:

```
user error (widgetGetDrawWindow: no DrawWindow available (the widget is probably not realized))
```

the program : 
- initializes the graphical stuff,
- computes the points to display,
- draws these points

there is no syntax nor compilation error, the above error is displayed when I launch the binary.

here is the code:

```
module Main where

import Graphics.UI.Gtk
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Gdk.GC
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Windows.Window
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Misc.DrawingArea
import System.Random
import           Control.Monad            (when,void)


k :: Int
k=100 -- 100 : after launching, u must wait less than 10s

mandelbrot :: Double -> Double -> Bool
mandelbrot a b =
  let
    mandelrec :: Double -> Double -> Int -> Bool
    mandelrec x y i
      | (x * x + y * y > 4) = False
      | (i==k) && (x * x + y * y <= 4) = True
      | otherwise = mandelrec x' y' (i+1)
            where x' = x * x - y * y + a
                  y' = 2 * x * y + b
  in mandelrec 0 0 0

colonnes :: Double -> [(Int, Double)]
colonnes w = [ (t,(fromIntegral t)/w*4-2) | t<-[0..((floor w)-1)] ]

lignes :: Double -> [(Int, Double)]
lignes h = [ (t,(fromIntegral t)/h*4-2) | t<-[0..((floor h)-1)] ]

points :: Double -> Double -> [((Int, Double), (Int, Double))]
points w h = [ (colonne,ligne)| colonne <- colonnes w,ligne <- lignes h]


main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Hello World"
  initGUI
  win <- windowNew
  onDestroy win mainQuit
  dAre <- drawingAreaNew
  dAre `onSizeRequest` return (Requisition 500 300)
  dAre `onExpose` drawCanvas dAre
  win `containerAdd` dAre

  --drawWin <- widgetGetDrawWindow dAre
  --drawWindowClear drawWin

  mapM_ (affiche dAre) ( points 500 300)


  widgetShowAll win
  mainGUI

affiche2 :: DrawingArea -> Int -> Int -> IO Bool
affiche2 can a b = do
  drawWin <- widgetGetDrawWindow can
  gece <- gcNew drawWin
  drawLine drawWin gece (a,b) (a,b)
  widgetQueueDraw can
  return True

affiche :: DrawingArea -> ((Int,Double), (Int,Double)) -> IO()
affiche can ((a0,a), (b0,b)) =
  when (mandelbrot a b) $ void (affiche2 can a0 b0)

drawCanvas :: DrawingArea -> event -> IO Bool
drawCanvas can _evt = do
  drawWin <- widgetGetDrawWindow can
  drawWindowClear drawWin
  gece <- gcNew drawWin
  x1 <- randomRIO (0,500)
  x2 <- randomRIO (0,500)
  y1 <- randomRIO (0,300)
  y2 <- randomRIO (0,300)
  drawLine drawWin gece (x1,y1) (x2,y2)
  widgetQueueDraw can
  --drawLine drawWin gece (10,10) (100,100)
  return True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things going on:

- I might be wrong about this, but I think `widgetQueueDraw` will only request a refresh of the canvas. Since you are drawing it already, my guess is that it will be ignored.
- Even if you tried to mark the canvas as *needs to be flushed to the screen buffer*, it's all running in the same thread and you have a pending computation until it's free to run other operations (such as flushing the canvas). So, everything will first be drawn, then be presented.

I don't think there's a clean way of forcing the canvas to be presented. If so, what you need is to use multiple threads. A working example follows (note that all Gtk operations need to be run in the UI thread, which is ensured by `postGUISync`). You need to compile it with the `-threaded` flag, which embeds and uses the threaded runtime system (aka RTS).

```
module Main where

import Control.Concurrent
import Graphics.UI.Gtk
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Gdk.GC
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Windows.Window
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Misc.DrawingArea
import System.Random
import           Control.Monad            (when,void)


k :: Int
k=100 -- 100 : after launching, u must wait less than 10s

mandelbrot :: Double -> Double -> Bool
mandelbrot a b =
  let
    mandelrec :: Double -> Double -> Int -> Bool
    mandelrec x y i
      | (x * x + y * y > 4) = False
      | (i==k) && (x * x + y * y <= 4) = True
      | otherwise = mandelrec x' y' (i+1)
            where x' = x * x - y * y + a
                  y' = 2 * x * y + b
  in mandelrec 0 0 0

colonnes :: Double -> [(Int, Double)]
colonnes w = [ (t,(fromIntegral t)/w*4-2) | t<-[0..((floor w)-1)] ]

lignes :: Double -> [(Int, Double)]
lignes h = [ (t,(fromIntegral t)/h*4-2) | t<-[0..((floor h)-1)] ]

points :: Double -> Double -> [((Int, Double), (Int, Double))]
points w h = [ (colonne,ligne)| colonne <- colonnes w,ligne <- lignes h]


main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Hello World"
  initGUI
  win <- windowNew
  onDestroy win mainQuit
  dAre <- drawingAreaNew
  dAre `onSizeRequest` return (Requisition 500 300)
  dAre `onExpose` drawCanvas dAre
  win `containerAdd` dAre

  widgetShowAll win
  mainGUI

affiche2 :: DrawingArea -> Int -> Int -> IO Bool
affiche2 can a b = do
  postGUISync $ do drawWin <- widgetGetDrawWindow can
                   gece <- gcNew drawWin
                   drawLine drawWin gece (a,b) (a,b)
  return True

affiche :: DrawingArea -> ((Int,Double), (Int,Double)) -> IO()
affiche can ((a0,a), (b0,b)) =
  when (mandelbrot a b) $ void (affiche2 can a0 b0)

drawCanvas :: DrawingArea -> event -> IO Bool
drawCanvas can _evt = do
  drawWin <- widgetGetDrawWindow can
  drawWindowClear drawWin
  gece <- gcNew drawWin
  forkIO $ mapM_ (affiche can) (points 500 300)
  return True
```

Comment: thanks, with a ramdom permutation of the points I get something nice! But I still have a lot of haskell to learn :-(

Answer (score 2):

well, I solved it by putting the mapM_ statement into the updateCanvas function, but all the drawing is displayed after all the points are computed, which is not what I would like to obtain : since the more tiny is the part of the mandelbrot set, the longer are the computations, I would like to see the drawing as it is created, not to wait a long time.

do you know how to reach this goal?

here is the working code:

```
module Main where

import Graphics.UI.Gtk
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Gdk.GC
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Windows.Window
import Graphics.UI.Gtk.Misc.DrawingArea
import System.Random
import           Control.Monad            (when,void)


k :: Int
k=10000 -- 100 : after launching, u must wait less than 10s

mandelbrot :: Double -> Double -> Bool
mandelbrot a b =
  let
    mandelrec :: Double -> Double -> Int -> Bool
    mandelrec x y i
      | (x * x + y * y > 4) = False
      | (i==k) && (x * x + y * y <= 4) = True
      | otherwise = mandelrec x' y' (i+1)
            where x' = x * x - y * y + a
                  y' = 2 * x * y + b
  in mandelrec 0 0 0

colonnes :: Double -> [(Int, Double)]
colonnes w = [ (t,(fromIntegral t)/w*4-2) | t<-[0..((floor w)-1)] ]

lignes :: Double -> [(Int, Double)]
lignes h = [ (t,(fromIntegral t)/h*4-2) | t<-[0..((floor h)-1)] ]

points :: Double -> Double -> [((Int, Double), (Int, Double))]
points w h = [ (colonne,ligne)| colonne <- colonnes w,ligne <- lignes h]


main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Hello World"
  initGUI
  win <- windowNew
  onDestroy win mainQuit
  dAre <- drawingAreaNew
  dAre `onSizeRequest` return (Requisition 500 300)
  dAre `onExpose` drawCanvas dAre
  win `containerAdd` dAre

  --drawWin <- widgetGetDrawWindow dAre
  --drawWindowClear drawWin

  --mapM_ (affiche dAre) ( points 500 300)


  widgetShowAll win
  mainGUI

affiche2 :: DrawingArea -> Int -> Int -> IO Bool
affiche2 can a b = do
  drawWin <- widgetGetDrawWindow can
  gece <- gcNew drawWin
  drawLine drawWin gece (a,b) (a,b)
  --drawLine drawWin gece (10,10) (100,100)
  widgetQueueDraw can
  return True

affiche :: DrawingArea -> ((Int,Double), (Int,Double)) -> IO()
affiche can ((a0,a), (b0,b)) =
  when (mandelbrot a b) $ void (affiche2 can a0 b0)

drawCanvas :: DrawingArea -> event -> IO Bool
drawCanvas can _evt = do
  drawWin <- widgetGetDrawWindow can
  drawWindowClear drawWin
  gece <- gcNew drawWin
  --x1 <- randomRIO (0,500)
  --x2 <- randomRIO (0,500)
  --y1 <- randomRIO (0,300)
  --y2 <- randomRIO (0,300)
  --drawLine drawWin gece (x1,y1) (x2,y2)
  mapM_ (affiche can) ( points 500 300)
  widgetQueueDraw can
  --drawLine drawWin gece (10,10) (100,100)
  return True
```

Comment: If you have another question you should ask another question instead of including it in your answer.